# How a Symfony 2 bundle can provide a "base" Doctrine entity, with the ability to "disable" the mappings?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

What i'm trying to accomplish: to make a bundle with a base Doctrine entity and a mapped superclass, giving the ability to reuse the bundle without actually use the entity (and use the mapped superclasses instead).

The problem: if I place my entities in the `Entity` namespace they are automatically mapped, along with tables. This would be fine for **Bundle A** but not for **Bundle B**.

Reusable bundle **mapped superclasses**:

- `OrderBundle\Entity\BaseOrder`
- `OrderBundle\Entity\BaseOrderDetail`

Reusable bundle **entities** (defining one-to-many and many-to-one associations):

- `OrderBundle\Model\SaleOrder`
- `OrderBundle\Model\SaleOrderDetail`

**Bundle A** needs `OrderBundle` entities, without customizing them. Mappings should be enabled.

**Bundle B** needs `OrderBundle` mappings, customizing the mapped superclasses (`OrderBundle\Entity`) and manually adds the associations. Mappings should be disabled..

I'm looking at the cookbook [How to provide model classes for several Doctrine implementations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html) and [How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) but I don't know if this is even possible.